# CSS file in ASP.NET, how to connect the css file in Content to the View MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I want to connect the css file in Content to a particular MVC view file.

In the MVC view file, I added a link element with every attributes, stylesheet, rel and href

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; we need to see a [mcve] to assist. Please edit the question by clicking the 'edit' option below the tags and adding your relevant code for the CSS file connection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.